# CutyCapt - unable to capture non-latin chars

Tags: qt, fonts, centos, xorg

i have install Qt44.* which includes libWebKit in order to compile and make the Cutycapt script/app as described at the project homepage (http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/)

The script runs but it is unable to capture non-latin fonts (e.g. Greek). When doing a screen capture for websites with latin characters everything works.

The script runs on a CentOS (x86_64) server [NO GUI] and xvfb is installed along with xvfb-run (/usr/bin/xvfb-run)

Guessed that it's a fonts issue so I have installed all xorg-x11-fonts* files and packages but no luck.

Anyone? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you contacted the author of CutyCapt? It seems unlikely that someone on SO knows what the problem is. Also, why are you not using the latest stable release of Qt (4.6)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply...just solved it. It was a fonts-issue - dejavu fonts package installed and problem solved. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For chinese, arabic and hindi I installed the following packages:

```
yum install fonts-chinese.noarch
yum install fonts-arabic.noarch
yum install fonts-gujarati.noarch
yum install fonts-hindi.noarch
```

(I'm running on CentOS 5 and hope this will help those using CutyCapt on there too).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with chinise symbols. I resolved it by to install kde package on my machine (kubuntu-desktop for Ubuntu) and it resolve my problem. As I understand qt + xorg-server libs not enought. I did know what libs were realy needed.